# Shevuah on Mitzvos

Tags: nedarim-shevuot

You can’t make a Shevuah against the mitzvos (ie: I won’t shake a Lulav). But can you make a double Shevuah, that neither goes against a mitzva, but together does(ie: I won’t shake any Lulav in this town. Then, I won’t leave this town)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would take effect, because neither oath directly contravenes a mitzvah. See Mishneh Torah, [Shvuot 5:18](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/973867/jewish/Shvuot-Chapter-5.htm#v18):

> נִשְׁבַּע שֶׁלֹּא יֹאכַל מַצָּה שָׁנָה אוֹ שְׁנָתַיִם. הֲרֵי זֶה
> אָסוּר לֶאֱכל מַצָּה בְּלֵילֵי הַפֶּסַח וְאִם אָכַל חַיָּב מִשּׁוּם
> שְׁבוּעַת בִּטּוּי. וְאֵין זֶה שְׁבוּעַת שָׁוְא שֶׁהֲרֵי לֹא נִשְׁבַּע
> שֶׁלֹּא יֹאכַל מַצָּה בְּלֵילֵי הַפֶּסַח אֶלָּא כָּלַל עִתִּים
> שֶׁאֲכִילַת מַצָּה בָּהֶם רְשׁוּת עִם עֵת שֶׁאֲכִילָתָהּ בּוֹ מִצְוָה
> וּמִתּוֹךְ שֶׁחָלָה שְׁבוּעָה עַל שְׁאָר הַיָּמִים חָלָה עַל לֵיל
> הַפֶּסַח. וְכֵן כָּל כַּיּוֹצֵא בָּזֶה. כְּגוֹן שֶׁנִּשְׁבַּע שֶׁלֹּא
> יֵשֵׁב בְּצֵל סֻכָּה לְעוֹלָם אוֹ שֶׁלֹּא יַעֲלֶה עָלָיו בֶּגֶד שָׁנָה
> אוֹ שְׁנָתַיִם
>
> One who takes an oath not to eat matzah for a year or two is forbidden
> to eat matzah on the nights of Pesach. If he eats it, he is liable,
> for violating a *sh'vuat bitui*. This is not considered as an oath taken
> in vain, since he did not take an oath [specifically] not to eat
> matzah on the nights of Pesach. Instead, he included the times when
> eating matzah is a matter of choice together with those when it is a
> mitzvah. Since the oath takes effect with regard to the other days, it
> also takes effect with regard to Pesach. Similar laws apply in all
> analogous situations, e.g., one took an oath not to sit in the shade
> of a sukkah forever, or not to wear a garment for a year or two.

See also Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah [236:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.236.5).